# Como fazer um select que retorna os dados de uma outra tabela Django

Tags: python, django, orm

Tenho uma tabela com nome "company" que se relaciona através de uma foreingkey com a tabela "enterprise". Para criar uma nova company fora do django admin, criei uma página html, mas não consigo fazer com que o select retorne os dados da tabela enterprise.

View para registrar a company

```
def register_company(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        enterprise = Enterprise.objects.all()

        name_company = request.POST['name_company']
        cnpj_company = request.POST['cnpj_company']
        area_company = request.POST['area_company']
        manager_company = request.POST['manager_company']
        email_company = request.POST['email_company']
        status = request.POST['status']
        logo_company = request.FILES['logo_company']
        enterprise = request.POST['enterprise']

        company = Company.objects.create(name_company=name_company, cnpj_company=cnpj_company, area_company=area_company,
                                         manager_company=manager_company, email_company=email_company, logo_company=logo_company,
                                         status=status, enterprise=enterprise)

        company.save()

        return redirect(enterprise, 'list_company')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register_company.html')
```

Parte da página HTML que deve retornar o select com os dados da tabela "enterprise")

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <label><b>Unidade</b></label>
           <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control form-control-md" name="enterprise" required>
                 {% for enterprise in enterprise %}
                    <option value="{{enterprise.id}}"> {{enterprise.enterprise_name}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
           </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

a pergunta esta confusa, mas pelo que entendi, você recebe o enterprise de um formulário, logo pode ser da seguinte forma.

```py
def register_company(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        name_company = request.POST['name_company']
        cnpj_company = request.POST['cnpj_company']
        area_company = request.POST['area_company']
        manager_company = request.POST['manager_company']
        email_company = request.POST['email_company']
        status = request.POST['status']
        logo_company = request.FILES['logo_company']
        enterprise = request.POST['enterprise']
        enter = Enterprise.objects.get(name_campo='enterprise')


        company = Company.objects.create(name_company=name_company, 
        cnpj_company=cnpj_company, area_company=area_company,
        manager_company=manager_company, email_company=email_company, 
        logo_company=logo_company,status=status, enterprise=enter)

        company.save()

        return redirect('name_app:list_company')

    else:
        return render(request, 'register_company.html')
```

Esta seria a view "create_company", agora você precisaria criar uma para listar todas as company's e uma view para os detalhes da company, é o mais correto a se fazer.

Leia também sobre "related_name" que vai te ajudar bastante.

Comment: e para evitar todo esse trabalho e muito código, pode usar modelForm.